# Trying to migrate Date values using migrate module.

Tags: 7, datetime, migrations

I'm trying to migrate some data from a csv to a field_collection in a user profile. Everythings works fine but not for a field of Date (with range) type.

I'm on Drupal 7.22 and I'm using Migration and Migration Extra modules

I do not receive any error message, but the data is not entered, please help me

My code in the migration class:

```
[...]
$source_file = drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/data/user_employments_info.csv';

$columns = array(
  [...]
  array('employment_period_start', 'employment_period_start'),
  array('employment_period_end', 'employment_period_end'),
  [...]
);

$this->destination = new MigrateDestinationFieldCollection(
  'field_usr_bkg_emplo',
  array('host_entity_type' => 'user')
);

[...]

$this->addFieldMapping('host_entity_id', 'user')->sourceMigration('User');

[...]

$this->addFieldMapping('field_usr_bkg_emplo_time', 'employment_period_start');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_usr_bkg_emplo_time:to', 'employment_period_end');
```

Comment: Probably a format issue? Have you checked what the format looks like before it gets passed to the fieldMapping? Probably you need to format it in a prepareRow() function?

Comment: I thought about it in fact I saved data with the simple form and I used the same format (YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00): a common datetime without tracking hours, minutes and seconds.
I used the format also literally in the code but I get the same result: nothing.

If I'm omitting something I'm sorry but I'm not an expert in Drupal

Comment: Probably this helps you? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56762/what-format-should-date-iso-date-be-when-using-migrate-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the base there was a problem: the module dates was patched.
The final code that have worked:

my.info

```
dependencies[] = migrate
dependencies[] = migrate_extras
dependencies[] = date
dependencies[] = date_migrate
```

my.make

```
projects[migrate][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[migrate][version] = "2.6-rc1"
projects[migrate_extras][subdir] = "contrib" 
projects[migrate_extras][version] = "2.5"
projects[date][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[date][version] = "2.6"
projects[date][patch][] = "https://drupal.org/files/date-consolidated_migrate-1.patch"
```

my_migration.inc

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_date', 'date_from');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_date:to', 'date_to');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_date:timezone', 'UTC');
```